# Unable to step into PresentationFramework

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, pdb-files, .net-4.7.2

I am trying to step into PresentationFramework, but the debugger just skips ahead to the next line.

- I have loaded the symbols using the Modules window.
  [image: PresentationFramework assembly path & version]
  [image: Loaded symbols path & version]
- I have enabled .NET Framework source stepping
- I have disabled Just My Code

I have used resharper to generate pdb and decompile the source, but stepping through those is really difficult. Partly because many variables have generic names (num1, num2 etc), but mostly because the debugger seemingly just around somewhat randomly - sometimes skipping lines, sometimes jumping backwards...

I have downloaded the .Net 4.7.2 source code from reference source; is there any way to step into that?

Comment: You can use [ilspy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) (basically an open source version of Reflector) to look at .NET assemblies. However that doesn’t get you to debugging into .NET source. Please check if the [following settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source?view=vs-2019) helps.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Thanks, but I already used dotPeek and Resharper to decompile. I also downloaded the complete source code from ReferenceSource. The problem is that I cannot deduce the program flow from the source code alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what did work was to upgrade to .Net 4.8. Maybe it only will until Microsoft releases a new version, but, for now, at least it works.